# load .mat file, but not on the workspace

Tags: matlab, save, load, workspace

```
if contains(p_path, 'left')
    save(left_path', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
    a = load(left_path);
elseif contains(p_path, 'right')
    save(right_path', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
    b = load(right_path);
end
```

left_path is defined as below (base path is like 'C:\Users\Documents')

```
left_mean_data_path = [base_path, '\left_data.mat'];
```

Running this code, I checked that file is created at correct folder with correct name (left_path), Which means that 'save' works well. However, 'load' those not work. the file 'left_data.mat' or variables 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' are not in the workspace.

To get those variables into workplace, I have to click the 'left_data.mat' file directly.

Can anyone help me??

- Above code is not in the main script, it's inside a function file. Is it the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `data = load(filename)` will load the contents of that matfile to a struct `data`. So inside `data`, you will find all the variables you saved.

However, if you execute this line in a function, the data will be loaded in the workspace of that function, and not the base workspace. Read [base and function workspaces](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html) and [share data between workspaces](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html).

The easiest method to get the data to the base workspace is to use `assignin` in the function. In your function, you would do:

```matlab
function myfunction()
    data = load(filepath);
    assignin('base', 'data',data); % base workspace, variable name in base workspace, variable to assign in base workspace
end
```